# Webpack 'mode' option has not been set

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, module

Fixed the problem. Make sure your webpack.config.js is in your root directory instead of your src folder.

### Why won't my terminal recognize 'production' from my files?

#### In my terminal after I execute npm run build, I get this:

```
WARNING in configurationThe 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value.Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
```

#### This is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js'
    }
};
```

#### This is part of my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cli": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

#### There is an index.js file in my src folder. I have tried updating npm to current version 9.8.1. Is it how I am exporting my code with module.exports? Should I be doing something different?

Comment: Have you tried if webpack will pick up the value as a command line argument (`webpack --mode=development`)? And is webpack using the other values in `webpack.config.js`? This might help narrow down the cause of the problem.